# Is there any contemporary philosophy about the nonduality I read about on web sites?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I have been studying Nonduality (Advaita, Emptiness and other approaches) for a couple years, using resources on the internet. There are lots of people writing blogs, books and giving interviews (such as on Conscious.TV and *Buddha At the Gas Pump*) about current experience of nondual awareness.

I would like to know who is writing about that in a secular way. One example is Sam Harris' 2014 bestseller: *"Waking Up - A Guide to Spirituality Without Religion"*. I think it is a good explanation which accords with my own experience. He cites a lot of research (and points out a lot of bad conclusions) from contemporary neuroscience and psychology. Is it Philosophy as well? I would say no.

Comment: I'm confused by your last two sentences "Is it Philosophy as well? I would say no."  How does this tie to your question (which I took to be are their philosophers who study non-duality from a non-religious perspective?) Could you perhaps edit to make your question clearer?

Comment: @virmaior: My meta-question is: Is there any point in me attempting to bring the subject of Nonduality (as I am using the term) to this site? I would say no, because if I am the first person to bring it up here, then either there is no one else interested or it is off-topic. So, I asked a question intended to test that hypothesis. Cheers!

Comment: @virmaior: this does not seem to fit here at all. Not sure where to go next.

Comment: @16869- Spinoza maintains that the 'motion and rest' which exists from the circulation of your blood the air you breath, the intake of oxygen through your skin, throughout the movement among people in motion, the winds, the oceans, the motion of the earth, the solar system, the galaxy, the entire cosmos, virtually the entire universe; that this 'motion and rest' combines the entire 'creata' into one contiguous entity. He called it 'facies totus universi'. Mind and matter and spirit are part of one integrated, eternal, infinite, self-perpetuation. See his TIE, and "Ethics" or 'substance monism'

Answer (score 4):

There is a vast literature on the topic. You mention Sam Harris but he is not a trustworthy source for this topic and seems to misunderstand it. The crucial piece of information you would need in order to relate nondualism to academic philosophy and onwards to physics is that it endorses a neutral metaphysical position. Once you 'grok' this then you will see that all this talk of nondualism being irrelevant, vague, anti-scientific, irrational, untestable and so forth is nonsense.

One problem you face is that for the nondual philosopher the focus is on exploration and experience, not book-learning, which means that much of the literature is little help to a philosopher seeking to understand nonduality within the framework of Western philosophical thinking. Not many pursue it as an academic topic and it can be  lonely field of research. One the plus side this means that researchers tend to quickly become relatively expert by general standards.

I cannot be sure what angle you wish to approach from or how much you know already, but some relevant references that come to mind would include...

Francis Bradley *Appearance and Reality*, George Spencer Brown *Laws of Form*, Radhkrishnan S *The Philosophy of the Upanishads*, Khenpo Gyamptso *The Sun of Wisdom*, Ulrich Mohrhoff *The World According to Quantum Mechanics*, Plotinus *Enneads*, Ramesh Balsekar *The Ultimate Understanding*

This is omitting the obvious mainstream texts such as the *Baghavad Gita*, the *Upanishads*, *A Course in Miracles* etc. The shortest introduction might be *Know Yourself* by Ibn Arabi. I happen to like the teachings of Wei Wu Wei, a friend of Spencer Brown, and there are a couple of useful websites devoted to him.

Among living philosophers I'd recommend any book by Rupert Spira. The choice is considerable but all the books say the same thing and Spira is very accessible.

Search terms would be 'nonduality', 'neutral metaphysical position', 'Unity', 'Unicity', 'Perennial philosophy', 'Middle Way', 'advaita'. The second of these may be the most productive if it's the formal aspect of nondualism that you're exploring, rather than enlightenment.

It's a little difficult to know who to mention since there are so many. If you want more targeted recommendations I'd need to know more about your particular interests.

Comment: Great. Still not a big topic on this SE though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean by nonduality, Georges Bataille's writing from 1939-1945 falls into this category. He never addresses the term nonduality specifically but a lot of his writing is along similar lines. In this answer I try to pick out a few concepts and ideas that bear a similarity to nonduality.

His philosophy revolves around the notion of pure subjective experience which he describes as "fusion of Subject and Object". His philosophy emphasizes experiencing everything and a refusal to reject anything from his experience in the world as he sees everything in subjective experience linking together in a thread that he refers to as Continuity.

He was initially interested in Christian Mysticism during this period but came to criticize it for including the idea of God and having Salvation as an end goal. For Bataille, all "sovereign" experiences lead to nowhere and the notion of God would thus represent another trap that would ground one in an experience that has a specified end. Any sovereign experience is one that includes a loss of self-mastery where the individual loses their sense of self/awareness in the moment and loses any ties to knowledge (where knowledge represents God in this particular case), the future, or any form of utility. It is unknowable because it lies outside objective awareness. Bataille is not exactly an Atheist but he does believe that the notion of God is not compatible with the notion of subjective experience as he describes it - it as an experience that is "free of any ties". In this sense his approach is definitely secular.

Finally, Bataille's work is based on a kind of duality between two types of systems but he argues that one of these systems (the heterogeneous system) disrupts the difference between its opposite (the homogeneous system) such that no differences exist. The result of this interaction is somewhat similar to certain descriptions of nonduality. Bataille describes himself as reversing Hegel's Dialectic which is based, in part, on knowledge. He believes that the structure of knowledge would collapse in the final dialectic before Absolute Knowledge could be attained, similar to the treatment of knowledge in some Hindu interpretations of knowledge. This brings about an "unknowable" state that he calls sovereignty.

I would suggest starting by reading the following books, collectively referred to as the Summa Atheologica (which was unfinished by the time he died). It includes the following: Inner Experience, Guilty, On Nietzsche, and The Unfinished System of Nonknowledge. For all of these books, the translation by Stuart Kendal is best in my opinion.

Comment: There isn't someone who is not French?

Comment: Well, what language/culture are you interested in? Authors in numerous East Asian traditions have written extensively on this topic. Are you interested in only English-speaking authors? If you cannot read French, most of Bataille's important works are translated into English and they are quite good. Nietzsche comes close at times (see jobermark's answers) but his works were originally written in German. Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Norman Mailer in *The White Negro* said: "Only the French, alienated beyond alienation from their unconscious could welcome an existential philosophy without ever feeling it at all; indeed only a Frenchman by declaring that the unconscious did not exist could then proceed to explore the delicate involutions of consciousness, the microscopically sensuous and all but ineffable frissons of mental becoming, in order finally to create the theology of atheism and so submit that in a world of absurdities the existential absurdity is most coherent." So French people disqualify themselves.

Comment: That seems likely a really poorly constructed and offensive generalization. I highly doubt that every single French writer/philosopher is the same in both thought or approach. I don't claim that Bataille will provide the answers you are looking for but as a word of advice, making blanket statements about groups of people, while both offensive and rude, is also a great way to alienate yourself from cultures and traditions that are different from your own.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be funny. It seemed ironic that the only reference you could offer was half a century old and French. I just thought the topic was a bit more current and widespread than that.

Comment: Well, sarcasm/humor is often lost online! It probably is more widespread than that but I don't know too much about it. Bataille is one philosopher whose work I am comfortable enough to post about on here so I thought I'd give my two cents. Good luck finding what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

I would claim that all philosophies involving intersubjectivity and non-determinacy, including all non-classical logic take something from the notion of nonduality.  In their own spirit, such choices are themselves non-dual, so these perspectives share the notion not in its radical form, but only in part.

This includes a huge space 'right in the middle' of modern philosophy whose corners I see vaguely as:

- transpersonal psychoanalyic approaches from Jung to Ken Wilbur in an psychological direction,
- consensualist notions of meaning and language from the late Wittgenstein to  DeSassure and Lacan in a logical direction,
- anti-objectivist stances generally considered 'nihilist' from that of the ancient Skeptics and Cynics to Neitsche's in an ethical direction, and
- by the standard models of quantum physics and a Kuhnian notion of scientific evolution in a scientific direction.

To put the relevant aspect I see in those contributions that are lifted straight out of either an Eastern or a Hermetic notion of non-duality most simply:

- (Jung/Wilber) If we are all part of one another, the duality of internal vs external reality, of self and culture, is just a matter of shifting perspective.
- (Wittgenstein/Desassure) If meaning is constructed by participation, the natural boundary between true and false interpretation is flexible, and dissolves at a small scale.
- (Diogenes of Sinope/Nietzsche) If genuine ethics derives from a culturally or personally selected sense of destiny, our shared rulesets are compromises we make with nature, that lack any real cohesion, may in fact not themselves be ethical, and again, break down in the fine grain.
- (Copenhagen QM) If none of our intuitions about the nature of space split our range of available models cleanly and still address the data, so that there is always a questionable area between existing or not existing, between being somewhere or everywhere, etc. then again, in any detail, we cannot be right about the facts and still truly understand what is really going on.
- (Kuhn/Feyerabend) And if our perspective on these things changes in ways that are not due to some direct logical mechanism, we are most right when we can handle multiple conflicting models at once, and sustain an ongoing sense of instability in our theories.

Comment: These are not the nonduality I was looking for. I wish to discuss the experience / perspective, not an idea.

Comment: Then you have answered your question beforehand, since philosophy is about ideas -- so someone should close the question as unrelated to philosophy.

But these are ideas, I think, that are available only because of that experience, especially Hermetics and other mystics having the experience and attempting to write about it, or to write instructions for getting there.

Comment: It is also pretty much condescending nonsense to insist that reality has a single basis, about which we make needless distinctions, and then nitpick the distinction between a perspective and an idea.  How is a perspective not an idea?  How is an experience not a memory?  Only in terms of a highly rigid dualism.

Comment: I am not sure what it means: "to insist that reality has a single basis". What else could it possibly have? I am just wishing to discuss the "nonduality" that I read about people currently exploring through Advaita, Emptiness, Self Inquiry and so on. If this does not belong here, I will take my lamp and keep wandering the streets.

Comment: The entire point of Advaita is the non-distinction between Atman and Brahman.  That what seems to be two worlds, really has a single basis.  It is not hard to see that this is what I mean, unless you are trying not to listen.

Comment: So how would you describe your experience of nonduality?

Comment: Describing such things is pointless.  Though not as pointless as distinguishing experiences from ideas...  Your entire motive here seems to be condescending, and not seeking information or meaning.

Comment: The point is to show people that nonconceptual awareness is in many ways preferable. Because they are stuck in a conceptual awareness, we must use concepts and descriptions to lead them beyond it, so it has a very definite point and value. If I slap you, is that an experience, or an idea? There is a difference. I am not being condescending at all, I want to find like-minded people.

Comment: Not 'nonconceptually'.  Your slapping is an activity outside myself.  But my perception of the slap is an idea.  Separating an experience from the effect it has on me, which is simply an idea, gives too much credence to the exact position that somehow one or the other is more real.

Comment: Deciding your position is preferable, beforehand, makes it crappy philosophy.  But it remains philosophy.  It has made appearances since the Stoics, and is very much a part of modern/post-modern thinking.

Comment: OK. Well, we differ in that I think that experiences are "more real" than ideas because they are the cause of ideas, and you think they are of equal standing. That is fine. I am not sure how we would ever come to agree on this point, which I find disheartening. Perhaps this is not the place to bring up nonduality then.

Comment: It is not a place to come with fixed conceptions.  Philosophers since at least Sextus Empiricus and Parmenides have placed a lot of value in this, and tried to allow it to influence their work.  So, you can 'bring it up', but only in a way that is not ultimately dismissive of all of us.

Comment: I am not the one who said something like "Describing such things is pointless." I have not tendered a position, I am just looking to see if any kind of conversation is possible about the topic.

Comment: The idea that the ideas I mention are not part of the same concept is a position.  It is an incorrect one.  And you have tendered it.

Comment: It is likely that I do not have enough background in this field and enough brainpower at the moment to see the connections that you have offered. I apologize for giving offense.

Comment: The important thing is to allow this awareness to influence you, not to describe it.  So many before us have attempted to describe it that I now consider that pointless.

Comment: I am sorry that I am not following your words, I am trying. Nonduality does influence me - it IS me. I have not had a self in a year and a half. Perhaps that makes it harder to understand some things. Lots of people are currently describing the same state in interviews and videos and blogs (see Lisa Cairns videos, although you have to be patient and a bit indulgent). People trying to get to that state see a point to these descriptions. But, it does not seem to fit the framework of Philosophy, or at least this site, so I will not bring it up further here. Thank you for the conversation.

Comment: user16869 - Nonduality does, as you have discovered, cause some problems here, but it is definitely a place to enquire about it. You would just need to be careful with the answers since this topic is off-piste for most members. But you seem to be capable of sorting the wheat from the chaff. If you want to open a chat room I would join you for a deeper discussion.

Comment: Off-piste? Or the reverse? It seems that you are no longer here.

Answer (score 2):

Swami Sarvapriyananda. That is the man you're looking for.

He talked about topics like Hard problem of consciousness and many atheistic questions.

He may not be secular in a Christian sense, but I haven't seen him outsource any question to some kind of miracle or to God (again in Christian sense. In Advaita, you're god. kind of.)

He is also very much involved in new neuroscience developments and psychology studies.

Some links:

[A random introductory video](https://youtu.be/AawWsJNi0gM)

[Another introductory level video](https://youtu.be/eGKFTUuJppU)

You can find many other videos in youtube, including some advanced level lectures.

[papers and talks](https://independent.academia.edu/SwamiSarvapriyananda)

Comment: Would you have links to sources for more information about him? This is an opportunity to point the reader to texts you find most useful by this author. Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nondual, philosophical treatment of spirituality and religion in Jacques Derrida's 'Of Spirit' and 'Acts of Religion', particularly in the latter's essay 'Hospitality'.

As an aside, note the connection between hospitality ([hospitable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hospital)), host, guest and ghost (latin spirit), all mentioned in these books.

Re. ghost - [Gæst in Beowulf (old English)](http://www.heroicage.org/issues/5/Anderson1.html)

> In this article, I discuss ... through an investigation of the
>   meanings of the word gæst, which appears initially to binarize a
>   social relationship into one of hosts and guests. Closer examination
>   of the word's Sanskrit root *ghas "to consume," highlights its
>   deconstruction as a differentiating marker of the most intimate of
>   social categories.
>
> ... In this text, there is an apparent opposition between the terms
>   gæst, "ghost, spirit, demon" and gist, "guest, stranger, visitor." ...
>   Gæst
>
> ... The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots notes that
>   gæst meaning "guest" derives from*ghos-ti, meaning "stranger, guest,
>   host," and "someone with whom one has reciprocal duties of
>   hospitality." Reflexes of the word include Germanic *gastiz, Latin
>   hostis "enemy" and Greek xenos, "stranger." Lewis and Short note that
>   Latin word hostis, derives from the Sanskrit root *ghas- to eat,
>   consume, or destroy" and that the Germanic gast is derived from the
>   same word. The compound of this word in Latin, hospes, adds the suffix
>   "pa" "to feed," thus combining the idea of feeding with the word for
>   stranger, and then contracting to "hospites" or "he who entertains a
>   stranger." The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots
>   gives gist as deriving from *gheis in an unclear original meaning,
>   having to do with "fear or amazement," with the "suffixed o-grade form
>   *ghois-do in Germanic *gaistaz, a ghost." The Oxford English Dictionary notes that word's etymological relations are "fury,
>   anger....the root "*gheis-, *ghois- appears with cognate sense in ON
>   geisa to rage, Gothic usgaisjan to terrify; outside Teutonic the
>   derivatives seem to point to a primary sense "to wound, tear, pull to
>   pieces." This last may suggest a link between the two original words,
>   since both roots have to do with consumption, with a possible
>   development from the relatively neutral *ghas- , "to consume", to the
>   more negative *gheis-, "fear."

Re. spirit - 'Of Spirit', page 98 (Derrida quoting Heidegger)

> What burns itself up is Being-outside-itself (das Ausser-sich) which
>   illuminates and makes shine, which also, however (indessen auch), can
>   devour tirelessly and consume everything up to and including the white
>   of the ash (in das Weisse der Asche verzehren kann).
>
> ... Trakl envisages "spirit" on the basis of this essence which is
>   named in the originary meaning (in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung) of
>   the word "Geist," for gheis means: to be thrown (aufgebracht),
>   transported [or transposed, deported: entsetzt, again -- and I believe
>   this is the most determining predicate], outside itself (ausser sich).

So a great deal revolves around this multiply extended proto-Indo-European root word 'gheis', all in a very nondual manner.

Comment: I know someone who likes at least some of what she read in Derrida, I have not encountered his writing. From what I see here, he is a Neo, and so is probably comprehensible only to himself. I was not really interested in religion, theology, or what is normally called spirituality. I am interested in the experience of nonduality, which is growing and widespread, and now, with Harris' book, in the mainstream. I only wondered if this subject is applicable to Philosophy as well. So that I could bring it up here. But it seems that if it was Philosophy, someone would already be discussing it.

Comment: From a [quick look](http://scienceandnonduality.com/tag/sam-harris/) it does appear Harris's duality is science vs supernatural.  My point shows that even spirit can be 'treated' non-supernaturally leaving everything nondual.  In such philosophy there is no duality, so the topic of 'nonduality' doesn't arise.

Comment: So for Philosophers, Nonduality is beneath consideration, like asking the mathematician what the plus sign means. OK. Thank you. No wonder they are all so far ahead of everyone else. Maybe we could discuss the issue of purpose and happiness. But those are solved problems for Philosophers also, I suspect. Like the ancient Brahmins that Alexander the Great met.

Comment: I mean at least some philosophers are in nondualist territory, even when they address 'non-science' topics that may ordinarily *appear* to be dualistic ones.

Comment: 'Chris - I would not want to downvote but feel it would have been better to mention only philosophers who endorse the nondual view.and show some understanding of it. Your point about there being no duality so no nonduality is subtle and it echoes Nagarjuna's point about the term 'Middle Way', that it is unnecessary since there are no other ways, but terms like 'Middle Way' and 'advaita' make it clear that for this view Reality is 'not-two' and so are extremely useful.  . .  . .  ,

Comment: @PeterJ Are you in effect asking for philosophers who endorse atheism?  I could suggest [Thomas Altizer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Gospel-Christian-Atheism/dp/1888570652).  However, I would mention that even Buddha only sought to bring discussion [down to earth](https://encyclopediaofbuddhism.org/wiki/The_unanswered_questions), so I offer a down-to-earth interpretation of the meaning of 'spirit'. We can do *Spirituality Without Religion*. Nevertheless it doesn't necessarily mean these authors don't harbour thoughts of a reality beyond the down-to-earth. Is that the duality of Religion here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment. Mine could have been a lot more clear. My quibble was that Derrida is not known for knowing anything about this topic and does not claim to do so, so he is an odd reference and there is no other given. It's hard enough to get into this topic at the best of times and thinking Derrida is a useful starting point might make it impossible, so I was prompted to make a critical comment. I should have made it more clearly.   . .

Comment: @PeterJ No problem. The duality is ambiguous, but is presumably between realistic *Spirituality* and supernatural *Religion*.  So I reference a realistic definition of 'spirit' to show how a central religious idea can be given a more realistic take.  I quote Derrida quoting Heidegger and add examples from Old English (Beowulf) to elaborate on the meaning of 'spirit' taken in a non-magical, realistic and down-to-earth way.

Comment: Okay. But this is not about non-dualism as a philosophy or explanation of the world.   .

Comment: @PeterJ Thomas Altizer probably deals with this quite specifically.  My own observations on the method of separating the realistic spiritual elements out of magical religion follow a similar direction, but only to show appeals to the supernatural are not necessary.  I'm not out to write-off the supernatural.

Comment: I don't mean to be merely awkward or annoying but have a problem in that I cannot connect your answer or comments with the OPs question about nondualist philosophers. Alitzer is interesting and relevant but he is not a nondualist philosopher and does not claim to be, and he does not explain this philosophy, albeit his ideas are definitely in the ball-park. Not arguing with what you say but just suggesting it is not much to do with the nondual philosophy. I'll make this the last comment since the system says I should and this all I had to say. .

Comment: Maybe I'm *being* a nondualist philosopher.

Answer (score 1):

"An analysis which is not merely a theoretical analysis, but at the same time another writing of the question of Being or meaning: deconstruction is also a manner or writing and putting forward another text. It is not a “tabula rasa”, which is why deconstruction is also distinct from doubt or from critique. Critique always operates in view of the decision after or by means of a judgment. The authority of judgment or of the critical evaluation is not the final authority for deconstruction. Deconstruction is also a deconstruction of critique. Which does not mean that all critique or all criticism is devalued, but that one is trying to think what the critical instances signifies in the history of authority. Deconstruction is not a critique. Another German word of which deconstruction is a kind of transposition is “Abbau,” which is found in Heidegger, and also found in Freud."  (Derrida)

mark alan forshee

Comment: Another comedian.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

Nonduality :A Study in Comparative Philosophy
 David Loy

The first book to examine thoroughly
 and demystify the concept of
 nonduality, a concept central to Asian
 religion and philosophy. Loy explains
 what Buddhist, Taoist, and Advaitic
 sages have thought about nonduality
 and also identifies references to
 nonduality in the work of Western thinkers.

Probably not the first book but relevant to your question.

Comment: All of Loy's books are worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

To put the old names to work, or even Just to leave them in circulation,
will always, of course, involve some risk: the risk of settling down or of
regressing into the system that has been, or is in the process of being,
deconstructed. To deny this risk would be to confirm it: it would be to see
the signifier-in this case the name-as a merely circumstantial , conventional
occurrence of the concept or as a concession without any specific
effect. It would be an affirmation of the autonomy of meaning, of the ideal
purity of an abstract, theoretical history of the concept. Inversely, to claim
to do away immediately with previous marks and to cross over, by decree,
by a simple leap, into the outside of the classical oppositions is, apart from
the risk of engaging in an interminable “negative theology,” to forget that
these oppositions have never constituted a given system, a sort of ahistorical,
thoroughly homogeneous table, but rather a dissymmetric, hierarchically
ordered space whose closure is constantly being traversed by the forces, and
worked by the exteriority, that it represses: that is, expels and, which
amounts to the same, internalizes as one of its moments.

(Derrida)

Comment: Welcome to SE, and thanks for contributing with a question/response! If you haven't done so, please take a quick moment to take the tour. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour More specifics can be found in the help center. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I was about to downvote the word-salad, then I saw it was by Derrida. Very amusing!